# String manipulation and aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a log collection in MongoDB that has a structure that looks like this:

```
{
  url : "http://example.com",
  query : "name=blah,;another_param=bleh",
  count : 5
}
```

where the "query" field is the query parameters in the requested url.
I want to compute a total of count grouped by the query parameter "name". For example, for this collection:

```
[{
 url : "http://example.com",
 query : "name=blah,;another_param=bleh",
 count : 3
},
{
 url : "http://example.com",
 query : "name=blah,;another_param=xyz",
 count : 4
},
{
 url : "http://example.com",
 query : "name=another_name,;another_param=bleh",
 count : 3
}]
```

I need this output:

```
[{
  key : "blah",
  count : 7
 },
 {
  key : "another_name",
  count : 3
 }]
```

It doesnt look like I can do this string manipulation using the aggregation framework. I can do this via map-reduce, but can a map-reduce operation be part of the aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregation framework does not have the string manipulation operators necessary to dissect the string content and break this up into the key/value pairs you need for this operation. The only string manipulation currently available is [**`$substr`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/), which is not going to help unless you are dealing with fixed length data.

So the only server side way to do this at present is with mapReduce since you can just the JavaScript functions available to do the right manipulation. Something like this:

For the mapper:

```js
function() {
     var obj = {};
     this.query.split(/,;/).forEach(function(item) { 
         var temp = item.split(/=/); 
         obj[temp[0]] = temp[1]; 
     });

     if (obj.hasOwnProperty('name')
         emit(obj.name,this.count);

}
```

And the reducer:

```js
function(key,values) {
   return Array.sum( values );
}
```

Which is the basic structure of the JavaScript functions required to split out the "name" parameters and use them as the "keys" for aggregation, or general counting of the "key" occurrences.

So the aggregation framework cannot execute any JavaScript itself, as it just runs native code operators over the data.

It would be a good idea though to look at changing how your data is stored, so that the elements are broken down into a an "object" representation rather than a string when the documents are inserted to MongoDB. This allows native query forms that don't rely on JavaScript execution to manipulate the data:

```js
[{
 "url": "http://example.com",
 "query": {
     "name": "blah",
     "another_param": "bleh"
 },
 "count": 3
},
{
 "url": "http://example.com",
 "query": {
     "name": "blah",
     "another_param": "xyz"
 },
 "count": 4
},
{
 "url": "http://example.com",
 "query": { 
     "name": "another_name",
     "another_param": "bleh"
 },
 "count": 3
}]
```

This makes a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage quite simple as the data is now organized in a form that can be natively processed:

```js
{ "$match": { "query.name": { "$exists": true } },
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$query.name",
    "count": { "$sum": "$count" }
}}
```

So use mapReduce for now, but ultimately consider changing your recording of the data to split the "tokens" from the query string and represent this as structured data, optionally keeping the original string in another field.

The aggregation framework will process this much faster than mapReduce can, so this would be the better ongoing option.

Comment: Thanks Neil for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi Neil, Do you know if there is a way to filter documents that are used in the map function by passing in a parameter. For example, I'd like to do the above aggregation only for documents whose "url" is "http://example.com". I have only the mapreduce option available at present.

Comment: @NavinViswanath mapReduce takes a standard query argument so you can specify what you need there. That is the best thing to do, but as shown above already, there is no need for the map function to emit anything, and you can just emit based on conditions in the logic there as is shown.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the query arguments to mapReduce, and that works for me. But how would I do that in the map function itself? Is there a way to pass parameters into the map function?